# Matterhorn dead but PID file exists

Tags: centos, init-script

Installed opencast-matterhorn14 in a Centos 6.5 Machine and after Installation steps while I try to run the Matterhorn using

`service matterhorn start`

I keep on getting the same error:

```
[root@matterhorn log]# /etc/init.d/matterhorn status
matterhorn dead but pid file exists
```

While looking in `/var/run` I saw there is a PIDFILE:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root     5 Jun 13 12:11 matterhorn.pid
```

So I removed the pidfile and tried to restart matterhorn, and I get the same error.

Whith Google search I found an `init` script for Matterhorn from [Github](https://github.com/lkiesow/matterhorn-scripts), so I have replaced my `init` script and still get the same error:

```
Matterhorn dead but pid file exists
```

If anyone have faced this issue please suggest a solution.